# Requests cannot connect to server with supplied .pem file, but urrlib3 works even without it

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, certificate, urllib3

I am trying to send HTTP requests to server (only accessible from specific network, so all names are made up) via requests lib, but I am getting SSL error.

My code:

```
site_auth = HTTPBasicAuth("user", "password")
response = requests.get("https://my.hidden.site.com", auth=site_auth , verify="location/src/mycertfile.pem")
```

I have tried also this:

```
site_auth = HTTPBasicAuth("user", "password")
response = requests.get("https://my.hidden.site.com", auth=site_auth , verify=True, cert="location/src/mycertfile.pem")
```

But the result was the same stacktrace.

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 361, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 377, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 724, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my.hidden.site.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "location/main_playground.py", line 15, in <module>
    response = requests.get("https://my.hidden.site.com", auth=rt_auth, verify="location/mycertfile.pem")
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "location\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my.hidden.site.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

I am using these versions of the libs:

```
requests==2.23.0
urllib3==1.25.9
```

I have googled a lot, but nothing works for me. I have manually downloaded the certification chain and created my .pem file which I have checked with openssl verify. I have 3 certificates in it and I have them ordered from the root to my target site in top to bottom fashion like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Weird thing is that urrlib3 works fine even without .pem file and explicitly enabled certificates, code:

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED')
r = http.request('GET', "https://my.hidden.site.com", fields={'user': "user", 'pass': "password"})
print(r)
print(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Another weird thing is that curl does not work by default, but works like it should when I supply the .pem file, so the requests should too, right?

```
curl https://my.hidden.site.com --cacert mycertfile.pem
```

I tried also Postman, but he does not work even with selected .pem file in the settings.

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://my.hidden.site.com.
```

I have also tried installing root and intermediate certificates on my machine (Windows 10), but it has no effect. Has anyone any idea what can be wrong or what should I check next?

Thanks for any help

// EDIT 1

I had created the chain of certificates by using this command and extracting the 3 keys from it. I have changed the order in the .pem file like I have already mentioned so the key of the root CA would be first in the .pem file and also the intermediate is second and the key for my.hidden.site.com is third.

I can see there are lines *unable to get local issuer certificate* and
*verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate*, but I do not know whether it is a problem or not, or maybe there is something missing.

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect my.hidden.site.com:443
CONNECTED(0000017C)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:SECRET LINE my.hidden.site.com
   i:SECRET LINE intermediate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:SECRET LINE intermediate
   i:SECRET LINE root ca
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:SECRET LINE root ca
   i:SECRET LINE root ca
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=SECRET LINE my.hidden.site.com

issuer=SECRET LINE intermediate

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4618 bytes and written 444 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: <HIDDEN_SESSION_ID>
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: <HIDDEN_MASTER_KEY>
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    <HIDDEN_SESSION_TICKET>

    Start Time: 1588693969
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
---

closed
depth=0 HIDDEN DETAILS, CN = my.hidden.site.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 HIDDEN DETAILS CN = my.hidden.site.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
requests.get("https://my.hidden.site.com", auth=site_auth , verify=True, cert="location/src/mycertfile.pem")
```

According to the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.request) `cert` is a path to client certificate, which is used in case of mutual TLS. This is when the server also validates your certificate, so it's not the case here.

`verify` is the path to a CA bundle.

> I have manually downloaded the certification chain and created my .pem

It depends on how you downloaded the cert chain, but servers don't send root CA certificate during TLS handshake. It's your job as a client to build the chain of trust. How to get it then? It depends on how was the my.hidden.site.com certificate generated. You could inspect the chain and see who is the issuer of the top-most certificate. If it's some global CA you can find the certificate online, but be careful with that.

> Another weird thing is that curl does not work by default, but works like it should when I supply the .pem file, so the requests should too, right?

That's true ;/.

I tested https://stackoverflow.com using actual CA, which was matched by the browser and the intermediate CA that was send during handshake and intermediate CA didn't work. You might be using the intermediate one, but it's really weird that curl worked.

EDIT: As I said earlier, CA is not sent in the handshake, so you won't see it in `openssl s_client` output. You can probably verify that by checking if the CA is self-signed. Check if the issuer is the same as subject.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61619780/9392216) on why specifying intermediate CA as `--cacert` won't work with curl below 7.68.0.