# Why does SSL connection fails when using intermediate CA?

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Given stackoverflow.com cert chain as follows:

`Builtin DST Root CA -> Let's encrypt intermediate CA -> *.stackexchange.com`

Is it possible to make a TLS connection using intermediate CA as trusted CA?

```
curl https://stackoverflow.com -v --cacert stack_intermediate_ca.pem --capath /dev/null -o /dev/null

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get issuer certificate
```

Is it because the intermediate CA is presented in the server chain during TLS handshake? Or do all certs in chain have to be signed either directly or transitively by a trusted authority?

I verified that the intermediate CA has `Is a Certification Authority` set in `Basic Constraints` attribute.

Maybe trusted CA has to be self signed, which is not the case with intermediate CA.

Comment: This may help: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63907/why-does-curl-need-both-root-and-intermediate-certificates-in-order-to-securely   But otherwise your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: "Is it because the intermediate CA is presented in the server chain during TLS handshake?" Servers have to provide the chain of certificates. They are just allowed to skip the root one, as the client should have it in its own truststore anyway.

Comment: "Or do all certs in chain have to be signed either directly or transitively by a trusted authority?" If you have a chain of certificates, it means each one is signed by the "previous" one so that you have a full link, that is a chain. Depending on which direction you view it, one of them will be signed by a root CA that is ultimately trusted by client, and one of them (same one or another, depending if the chain of intermediates has only one certificate or more) will sign the end user certificate. That way you have a full chain from trusted CA to endpoint certificate.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yeah, I know the theory, but what's wrong with pointing the intermediate CA as ultimately trusted on the client side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior here depends on the version of openssl and curl.

Traditionally openssl required the verification of the full chain, i.e. up to the self-signed and locally trusted root certificate. With openssl 1.0.2 the flag [X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags.html) was added, which allowed the chain verification to end in an arbitrary trusted certificate, no matter if it is the self-signed root or not. But this behavior is off by default.

With curl 7.68.0 curl has this flag enabled by default, so that with newer versions of curl and openssl it should be possible to have a chain certificate in `--cacert` instead of the self-signed root certificate. It does not matter if the server will send more chain certificates then needed to verify the chain since curl/openssl will just use the certificates which are actually needed. Verified with curl 7.68.0 with openssl 1.1.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.